# Using unsigned int as array index could lead to buffer overflows?

Tags: c, security, scanf, buffer-overflow, unsigned-integer

I have this code in which I have to find security vulnerabilities.

```
win() {
    printf("Congratulations!");
}
setter(unsigned int i, int v, int * a) {
    a[i] = v;
}

main() {
    int i, v;
    int a[50];
    puts("i");
    scanf("%d", i);
    puts("v");
    scanf("%d", v);
    setter(i, v, a)
}
```

Reading on the Internet, I've found that when a conversion from an `int` to an `unsigned int` takes place, if the int is a negative number, it will be converted into a very high unsigned int. So, probably the vulnerabilty in this code is due to this conversion which takes place when `setter` is called in the `main` function. So, an attacker could give the following input: `i=-1`, `v=40` and he will access to a part of the memory which isn't reserved to the buffer `a` and so, in the `setter` function, the attacker will be able to overwrite important values. For example, the attacker could overwrite the return address with the address of the `win` function in order to execute `win` when `setter` returns. Am I right?

Comment: OT: Are you aware that `scanf` wants a pointer? `scanf("%d", &i);` instead of `scanf("%d", i);`?

Comment: Yes, I know that scanf wants a pointer, but the code wasn't written by me.  It is an exercise that has been given to me. So probably the problem is the one that you mentioned? @DavidRanieri

Comment: Coud be, keep in mind that since you are passing garbage (an uninitialized value) to the function, the behaviour is undefined and at this moment anything could happen. But answering your question, no, using `unsigned` instead of `signed` or viceversa doesn't prevent buffer overflows, a buffer overflow occurs when you write outside the limits of the array, the type of the offsett doesn't matter.

Comment: So there is still the possibility of a buffer overflow as `a` is not initialized and passed to another function, but this problem doesn't depend on the fact that `int` is converted into `unsigned int`, right? @DavidRanieri

Comment: `a[i] = v;` is a vulnerability. The user can enter any index `i`. Signed or unsigned in't an issue (nor is the fact the `a[]` has not been initialised), it is the unchecked *range* of the index that is a problem.

Comment: So a buffer overflow could happen when` i`  is grather than 50 because the attacker will be able to write what he wants outside the size of the array? @WeatherVane

Comment: @Joanne The problem is not with `a`, but with  `i` and `v` being used uninitialized, what could happen in the conversion from `signed` to `unsigned` is: a negative number is converted to a positive number, i.e `unsigned char c = (char)-127;` -> `c = 129`

Comment: ` i`  and ` v`  are initialized with the scanf, aren't they? @DavidRanieri

Comment: @Joanne `if(i < 0 || i >= 50) perror("Index out of range");`

Comment: What makes you think passing -1 is not Undefined Behavior? If anything, small negative values may allow attacker to change something important, whereas unsigned int max is much more likely to cause immediate crash.

Comment: @Joanne Nops, `scanf` doesn't touch/alter these variables, as I said, you need an ampersand: `scanf("%d", &i);` and `scanf("%d", &v);`

Comment: @WeatherVane yes, so is it possible to have a buffer overflow with indexes out of range?

Comment: @DavidRanieri ok, what can happen if these variables are uninitialized?

Comment: You *always* get buffer overflow when the index is out of range.

Comment: Apart from the errors not using a pointer with `scanf` the main fault is *not validating the input*. It's a major crime: go directly to jail and do not pass Go. Even when nobody else is using the program, I need to protected *against myself* making typos and errors.

Comment: @hyde what I wanted to say is that passing -1 means that this ` int' will be converted into a very big ` unsigned int`  which will probably be a number out of  the array range. This will problaly lead to a buffer overflow because the attacker will be able to overwrite values out of the array bounds.

Comment: @Joanne yes, -1 will be converted to a very large number. But passing i=50 or i=51 is already a buffer overflow, because the array can only hold 50 elements.

Comment: @Joanne signed -1 will also cause buffer overflow (or underflow, or index out of bounds or however you want to call it). It's no less wrong than 0xFFFFFFFFu, and is arguably a bit more dangerous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary of some comments and some additions

Firstly, the code is wrong. The arguments to `scanf` needs to be pointers:

```
scanf("%d", &i); // Note the &
```

> if the int is a negative number, it will be converted into a very high unsigned int.

Yes, this is technically true, and it's also true that this may lead to accessing the array out of bounds. However, even if you change to unsigned, there is nothing preventing the attacker from simply typing any number, including whatever the number `(unsigned) -1` will be on the particular system.

The correct way of solving this security issue is to check that the inputted number are in the range [0,49]. If you use an unsigned number, you may skip checking if it's below zero for obvious reasons. But you still need to do a range check.